# Why do guys record output from po-33 to tascam dr 05 and not to the computer

Tags: recording

I saw a lot of videos on YouTube and no one records to the computer

Quality will be different or what?

Comment: Can you explain more about your question? What is a po-33? When you say "no one records to the computer" what do you mean? Many people record using computers so it's not clear what you're talking about.

Comment: The Teenage Engineering PO-33 KO is a micro sampler designed to provide easy and creative sound creation and sequencing for producers. 
Look for on YouTube "po-33 tascam dr.05"; None of these people record the output from po-33 to the computer in line-in; they all have voice recorders, or it's completely incomprehensible where the sound is written and why such a prohibitive quality :)

Comment: If you search YouTube for "po-33 tascam dr 05", wouldn't you expect to always find videos of people using the DR 05 for recording? That's all the DR 05 does, so if it's in the video, it's being used to record something. What is it being used to record? Well the **other** thing that's sure to be in the video: the PO-33. Why would the DR 05 be in the video if it wasn't used to record? If you search YouTube for "po-33", you'll find tons of videos of people recording the PO-33 using a computer or something else.

Comment: I have never found . And the second question was just about the sound quality - because the computer sounds like nothing (it does not count at all - the computer sounds disgusting - does not sound at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  "Teenage Engineering PO-33 KO Pocket Operator Micro Sampler" has a stereo line output.

In the videos you were looking at the people were probably sending to the Tascam because it has a stereo mic input that can capture both channels of the signal, while their computer sound card only has a mono line or mic input that would miss one channel.

In some of the videos I looked at, users are connecting to various types of equipment, including DJ gear and other recording equipment, all of which likely had the capability for accepting a stereo signal.